# Haikuifier (Or at least Haiku Identifier)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, natural-language-processing

All the usual stuff. Style, substance, algorithm please! I'm vaguely considering plugging it into a bot, hence the lacklustre catching of exceptions right now.

```
import requests
import sys

def get_num_syllables(value):
    try:
        res = requests.get("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/" + value)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        return -1

    for word in res.text.split():
        if "<h2>" not in word:
            continue
        word = word[word.find("<h2>")+ 4:word.find("</h2>")]

        if '·' in word:
            return word.count('·') + 1
    if "Word not found in the Dictionary and Encyclopedia." in res.text:
        return -1
    return 1

def haikuify(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.strip()
    num_syllables = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        num_syllables.append(get_num_syllables(word))

    if -1 in num_syllables:
        raise SyntaxError("Someone can't spell - can't find a word from the sentence in the dictionary")

    haiku_form = [5, 7, 5]
    haiku_indices = []
    i = -1
    run = 0
    line = 0

    for value in num_syllables:
        run += value
        if run is haiku_form[line]:
            haiku_indices.append(i)
            line += 1
            run = 0
        elif run > haiku_form[line]:
            raise SyntaxError("Not a haiku")
            break
        i += 1

    haiku_indices.append(len([len(x) for x in sentence.split()]) - 1)

    if len(haiku_indices) is not 3:
        raise SyntaxError("Not a haiku")

    i = -1
    line = 0
    this_line = ""
    haiku = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        word = word.replace(" ", "")
        if not word:
            continue

        this_line += " " + word
        i += 1
        if i is haiku_indices[line]:
            haiku.append(this_line)
            this_line = ""
            line += 1

    return haiku

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentence = input("Sentence to haikuify: ")
    haiku = []
    try:
        haiku = haikuify(sentence)
    except SyntaxError as err:
        print(err.msg)
    print(haiku)
```

Comment: A usage example would really help. Also maybe help the user more when saying `This is not a haiku` and tell them how many syllables were missing (or too much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more helpful to the user, both when the entered sentence can't be made into a haiku (too short or too long) and when not finding the word in the dictionary. At least tell *which* word was not found in the dictionary.

Also when `thefreedictionary.com` is not reachable (for whatever reasons), your code will insult the user by telling him he can't spell.

You dictionary lookup fails for some words:

- "sparrow's", or any possessive form (raises SyntaxError)
- "banging", or any gerund form. (gives the syllables of the infinitive instead)
- Any punctuation (also raises SyntaxError)

I tested your program with this haiku from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku_in_English):

> Snow in my shoe
>
> Abandoned
>
> Sparrow's nest
>
> — Jack Kerouac, collected in Book of Haikus, 2003

And this:

> Whitecaps on the bay:
>
> A broken signboard banging
>
> In the April wind.
>
> — Richard Wright, collected in Haiku: This Other World, 1998

The first raises a `SyntaxError` and the second puts `In` on the end of the second line because of the gerund counting as one less syllable.

What your code also does not catch is that thefreedictionary puts a flood mechanism into place after some time. I found this out by testing my own script. In this case the fifth request in a row returns with HTTP code 403 (Access forbidden).

---

How I would write it:

```
import requests
import sys
import re


def get_num_syllables(value):
    if value.endswith("ing"):
        return get_num_syllables(value[:-3]) + 1
    try:
        res = requests.get("http://www.thefreedictionary.com/" + value)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("Can't connect to dictionary website: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/" + value)
        sys.exit(1)
    if res.status_code != 200:
        raise requests.exceptions.ConnectionError("Can't connect to dictionary website: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/{}, HTTP code {}".format(value, res.status_code))
    value_re = re.compile(value)
    for word in res.text.split():
        if "<h2>" not in word:
            continue
        word = word[word.find("<h2>") + 4:word.find("</h2>")].lower()
        if '·' in word:
            match = re.match(word.replace('·', ''), value)
            if not match:
                continue
            return word.count('·') + 1
    not_founds = ("Word not found in the Dictionary and Encyclopedia.",
                 "is not available in the general English dictionary")
    if any(not_found in res.text for not_found in not_founds):
        raise SyntaxError("Can't find word in dictionary: {}".format(value))
    return 1


def get_num_syllables_all(words):
    syllables = {}
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        if word in syllables:
            continue
        syllables[word] = get_num_syllables(word)
    return syllables


def haiku(words, haiku_form):
    # words = "Whitecaps on the bay A broken signboard banging In the April wind".split()
    num_syllables = get_num_syllables_all(words)

    lines = [[] for _ in range(len(haiku_form))]
    count, line = 0, 0
    for word in words:
        count += num_syllables[word.lower()]
        if count > haiku_form[line]:
            raise SyntaxError("Not possible to split word at syllable boundary: {}, {}".format(word, syllables))
        lines[line].append(word)
        if count == haiku_form[line]:
            line += 1
            count = 0

    # validate the haiku
    for i, line in enumerate(haiku_form):
        sum_line = sum(num_syllables[word] for word in lines[i])
        if sum_line > line:
            raise SyntaxError("Too many syllables in line {}. Got {}, want {}".format(i, sum_line, line))
        elif sum_line < line:
            raise SyntaxError("Not enough syllables in line {}. Got {}, want {}".format(i, sum_line, line))
    return "\n".join(" ".join(line) for line in lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    haiku_form = (5, 7, 5)
    words = input("Please enter the words to use: ").strip().split()
    try:
        print(haiku(words, haiku_form))
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print(e)
```